# fork/exec causes app indicator to stick around?

Tags: linux, fork

I have an app indicator program I wrote for Ubuntu Linux.  It dynamically loads a menu of launch items.  When you launch an item with a simple `fork()` call followed by an `exec()`, the child process runs fine and then when it's done it exits.  However, when I exit the main application and the child is still running the app indicator menu stays and doesn't exit despite the fact that the parent has gone.  The menu then appears to be unresponsive except I can select items in it but nothing happens.  Selecting quit from it also doesn't do anything.

From what I can tell this has something to do with the way fork() works.
As it creates a child process that is identical to the parent.  So the child will hold open all the same files/references etc that the parent holds open.
However, I exec after the fork.  Could those references be remaining?

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Close the files before the exec?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  Although isn't going to be easy because of the way this app is written.  The fork is buried in an API shared across multiple platform ports.

Comment: Is there perhaps  a way to run a separate process without fork?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the exact problem is without the actual code. One bit of information which may or may not help you is that there is an `open` flag, `O_CLOEXEC`, which will close the file descriptor when `exec` is called so that the child process will not have that open.

Comment: Thanks, I can't really post the code it's too large.  But I might be able to mok something up that demonstrates it.  It's really just the app indicator.  There are no other open files.  The app indicator stays.  And any other gtk gui components stay as well and become unresponsive once the parent exits.  I tried calling gtk_main_quit() before the exec and after the fork but it didn't work.

Comment: It's a bit of a big hammer but perhaps a bit of infanticide to kill all the children with `kill(0)`. Assuming the child processes have not explicitly changed process groups.

Comment: Thanks.  I have found a solution.  But also, your suggestion is a good one.  I can check if there are still child processes and pop up a warning with a dialog to ignore the warning or just kill all children.